# What do you call symbols that represent multi-character operations?

Tags: visual-studio-code, character

So I recently read an article that I can no longer find that talked about a setting available in Visual Studio Code where you can have the editor represent certain operations in a single character that normally take more. It's sort of a setting that makes code look a little prettier.

For instance, instead of showing an arrow function as `=>` it would draw a little arrow like this ⇒. It did a similar thing for `<=`, `>=`, `===` and others.

I'd like to enable the setting but I don't even know what to search for to find it. Does anyone know the setting, or at least know what that class of characters are called?

Comment: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/VS-Code-Instructions

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize I'd have to change fonts. I really love the default one so I'll just have to see how I feel after trying it for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was font ligatures.